# Why Typescript sometimes doesn't allow to set value if it's structurally compatible with the type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

TypeScript is using structural typing and that's fine, but I noticed that it sometimes complains when there is no difference structurally. Why does it happen? What's going on here?

Example:

```
enum TagType {
    SIMPLE = 'simple',
    COLLECTOR = 'collector',
}

interface CollectorTag {
    type: TagType.COLLECTOR,
}

const tag1_1: CollectorTag = {
  type: TagType.COLLECTOR,
};

const tag1_2 = tag1_1;


const tag2_1 = {
  type: TagType.COLLECTOR,
};

const tag2_2: CollectorTag = tag2_1;
      ^^^^^^
      Error here
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKghgcxgTwA7CgbwFBT1AZQEkBZABQBkBRKAXigHIBnASwlQBtgGAaXfAMIB5CtQEwhAJTqMAxgHsOXWQBd5AJ17YAvtmwsQK4OoBmcWRgGLla9fARZ+eFWmAAuWIhToAdMNFU4lJ8utgKIEwqUCqIAIwA+rEeVkrAqhr2MjjOrh723sB+ImISkiEA3HrhkdFx8QBMMjEICbGVemHyEVHN9YlZ-C7oeV6uRQFBZTqVAPQzUEQmUJHqYKpg6nBKyNEAFsYYLExQIPIquwYOACYsJiYHhjx7oFAA7rs7V-JvGLtwAG4YYzqDRQfbqYAAfk63VqCD69WS1jStky9F6iXKQA)

Comment: The type of `tag2_1` is inferred to be `{ type: TagType; }` by the compiler, so you'd be allowed to write `tag2_1.type = TagType.SIMPLE` if you wanted later.  So that type and `CollectorTag` are different and you can't assign the former to the latter.  It doesn't realize that your intent was that the `type` property should *always* be `TagType.COLLECTOR`.  To communicate that intent, you can use a `const` assertion like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8Kg0W), and it all works. If that makes sense I can write up an answer; otherwise, please elaborate on what's missing for you.

Comment: Or @TitianCernicovaDragomir can do it 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because those types are not really compatible `tag2_1.tag` can be any `TagType`, while `tag1_1.tag` is a specific value of the enum `TagType.COLLECTOR`.

Literal value types exist in typescript, meaning that a value can act as a type and only the specific value is assignable to such a literal value type. They are usually useful with unions

Using `as const` will make typescript infer  `tag2_1.tag` as the literal type too

```
const tag2_1 = {
  type: TagType.COLLECTOR,
} as const;
const tag2_2: CollectorTag = tag2_1;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKghgcxgTwA7CgbwFBT1AZQEkBZABQBkBRKAXigHIBnASwlQBtgGAaXfAMIB5CtQEwhAJTqMAxgHsOXWQBd5AJ17YAvtmwsQK4OoBmcWRgGLla9fARZ+eFWmAAuWIhToAdMNFU4lJ8utgKIEwqUCqIAIwA+rEeVkrAqhr2MjjOrh723sB+ImISkiFQANx64ZHRcfEATDIxCAmxVXph8hFRLQ2JWfwu6HlerkUBQWU6UHBMUDUqVYt1CP0NydZptpn0fYkVQA)

Comment: Thank you! It feels like a tricky question that could be used in an interview to confuse the candidate lol.